# Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551when using phpMyAdmin

Tags: phpmyadmin, ubuntu-18.04, apache2.4, php-7.2, mariadb-10.1

I have an issue that I have researched to find a solution for but any of the fixes that have been provided cause a far worse error so I am hoping someone can guide me here.

Here is the error I get when I try to use the Import feature in phpMyAdmin

Warning in ./libraries/plugin_interface.lib.php#551
 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Below you will find the statement in which the error refers.

```
        if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {
            foreach ($options->getProperties()
                as $propertyMainGroup
            ) {
                // check for hidden properties
                $no_options = true;
                foreach ($propertyMainGroup->getProperties() as $propertyItem) {
                    if (strcmp('PMA\libraries\properties\options\items\HiddenPropertyItem', get_class($propertyItem))) {
                        $no_options = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                $ret .= PMA_pluginGetOneOption(
                    $section,
                    $plugin_name,
                    $propertyMainGroup
                );
            }
        }
```

Which according to what I have found, this is the fix suggested.

```
correction to the operation on lines #551-570 in the file: plugin_interface.lib.php

if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {
            foreach ($options->getProperties()
                as $propertyMainGroup
            ) {
                // check for hidden properties
                $no_options = true;
                foreach ($propertyMainGroup->getProperties() as $propertyItem) {
                    if (strcmp('PMA\libraries\properties\options\items\HiddenPropertyItem', get_class($propertyItem))) {
                        $no_options = false;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                $ret .= PMA_pluginGetOneOption(
                    $section,
                    $plugin_name,
                    $propertyMainGroup
                );
            }
        }
```

When I make the change as specified, which is to change the line

```
 if ($options != null && count($options) > 0) {
```

to

```
if ($options != null && count((array)$options) > 0) {
```

In all cases, sudo service apache2 restart was run after changes made.

However when just opening phpMyAdmin after the proposed change, I get the following error which is no longer isolated to just the "import" function.

> I get the following error:
>   "Error in processing request
>   Error code: 500
>   Error text: Internal Server Error"

While all the parenthesis have a corresponding one, and from everything I can tell it is syntactically correct, there is still something that is not being liked by I am guessing either php or phpMyAdmin, either way, I could use some help because I need to export a database to another server, and I only know how to do it with phpMyAdmin.

Other then the "fix" I found for this, the person to whom this answer was given also replied that this fix suggestion caused the same failure after implementing and asked the person to please help clarify since it did not work, but oddly enough the person never replied back, so this is why I have come to the experts.

I am running the following:

Server version: 10.1.43-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 Ubuntu 18.04
Server version: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2019-09-16T12:58:48
PHP 7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2 (cli) (built: Jan 13 2020 18:39:59) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.2.24-0ubuntu0.18.04.2, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

All packages have been upgraded to the latest using apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade

So I am running the latest of the packages I am using. The reason I am using php7.2 is because some of the web apps I have installed on this server require that version and have no instructions for upgrading past that version.

If I can supply any additional information please let me know.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Systop

Answer (score 1):

Since I could fine no other solutions for this, I manually upgraded phpMyAdmin to the latest release of phpMyAdmin that they have on their site.

This has resolved the issue. If anyone else runs into this issue, rather then trying to figure out how to fix the syntax errors in the files, I highly recommend following the steps on this page and simply modify the paths to match your installation on your server.

[Upgrade phpMyAdmin posted by DevAnswers.co](https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/https://devanswers.co/manually-upgrade-phpmyadmin/)

The steps outlined in this site are very easy to understand and implement. Once you complete the install, you should have no issues using the import / export features and any other areas where this problem would arise.